# Adding space between <span>'s

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm trying to make each `<span>` a new paragraph or add a break between each.

**Here is my code:**

```
<div class="post_custom_fields">
    <?php                                                        
        if (isset($gt3_theme_pagebuilder['page_settings']['portfolio']['skills']) && is_array($gt3_theme_pagebuilder['page_settings']['portfolio']['skills'])) {
            foreach ($gt3_theme_pagebuilder['page_settings']['portfolio']['skills'] as $skillkey => $skillvalue) {
                echo "<span>" . esc_attr($skillvalue['value']) . "</span>";
            }
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Any help would be super appreciated!

Here is a picture of how the info is currently displaying on the website without any spacing between the fields I entered.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use use `<p>` instead of `<span>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about using a break?

```
<div class="post_custom_fields">
    <?php
        if (isset($gt3_theme_pagebuilder['page_settings']['portfolio']['skills']) && is_array($gt3_theme_pagebuilder['page_settings']['portfolio']['skills'])) {
            foreach ($gt3_theme_pagebuilder['page_settings']['portfolio']['skills'] as $skillkey => $skillvalue) {
               echo "<span>" . esc_attr($skillvalue['value']) . "</span><br/>";
            }
        }
   ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3653376 no problem, could you do me a favor and accept the answer? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are asking for is either:

```php
<div class="post_custom_fields">
<?php
    if (isset($gt3_theme_pagebuilder['page_settings']['portfolio']['skills']) && is_array($gt3_theme_pagebuilder['page_settings']['portfolio']['skills'])){
        foreach ($gt3_theme_pagebuilder['page_settings']['portfolio']['skills'] as $skillkey => $skillvalue) {
            echo "<span>" . esc_attr($skillvalue['value']) . "</span><br />";
        }
    }
?>
</div>
```

OR

```
<div class="post_custom_fields">
<?php
    if (isset($gt3_theme_pagebuilder['page_settings']['portfolio']['skills']) && is_array($gt3_theme_pagebuilder['page_settings']['portfolio']['skills'])) {
        foreach ($gt3_theme_pagebuilder['page_settings']['portfolio']['skills'] as $skillkey => $skillvalue) {
            echo "<p>" . esc_attr($skillvalue['value']) . "</p>";
        }
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks TylerH,  I was working on that as you had made the changes.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use some CSS on the *span* element

```
.post_custom_fields > span { 
    clear:both;
    display: block;
    margin: 2px 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<span>" . esc_attr($skillvalue['value']) . "</span> <br>";
```

or

```
echo "<p><span>" . esc_attr($skillvalue['value']) . "</span></p>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!